# How to pass variables between Event Subroutines(vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

So I'm making a game in Vb.net. I use a 2D array in one subroutine where it executes when buttons are pressed. So I've defined the variables in a subroutine where the keys are pressed.

```
Private Sub GameScreen_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress

    Dim r = 5 - 1
    Dim GameState(r, r)
```

And I want to use the "r" and "GameState" variables in another event subroutine

```
Private Sub GameScreen_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For no = 0 To r
        For no2 = 0 To r
            If GameState(no, no2) = 0 Then
                Counter += 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

However when I try to add another parameter in the subroutine like so, it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub GameScreen_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs, ByRef GameState(,) As Integer) Handles MyBase.Load
    For no = 0 To r
        For no2 = 0 To r
            If GameState(no, no2) = 0 Then
                Counter += 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add parameters to event handlers. You can use a class-level variable. Just put your r variable class level and share it with other methods.

```
Public Class Test
    Private r As Integer

    Public Sub Method()
        ' You can use r here
    End Sub

    Public Sub Method2()
        ' You can also use r here
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: FYI, `Shared` has a different meaning in VB.  The technically accurate way to describe a class-level variable like that in VB is a _field_.  Otherwise, good answer :)

Comment: correct. Thanks for clarification, edited the answer :)